# How to add routes for a static directory and an Angular client on the same server?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have an API written in Node.JS/Express and an Angular client that talks to it, both in the same server. All HTTP calls that are not recognized by the API are automatically redirected to the client.

My current code looks like this and it is working as expected so far:

```js
app.get('/api/something', (req, res) => {
 //...
});

app.get('/api/foo/bar', (req, res) => {
 //...
});

// (...)

app.use(express.static('client'));    
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('client/index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '..') });
});
```

Now I need to add to this a route to a directory with static files (for example, `stuff`, so that URLs like `/stuff/xxx/yyy.png` would return the corresponding file), but still falling back to the Angular client for everything else.

How can I achieve this? So far, everything I tried would either not work at all or break the client routes.

---

**Edit:** Based on the answer by joyBlanks, this is what ended up working for me:

(The redirect is necessary to correctly handle URLs that point to a directory name without the trailing slash)

```js
app.get('/*', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.url.startsWith('/stuff')) {
        res.sendFile(
            req.url.substr(1), { root: path.join(__dirname, '..') },
            err => {
                if (err) {
                    if (err.code == 'EISDIR')
                        res.redirect(req.url + '/');
                    else
                        next(err);
                }
            }
        );
    }
    else {
        res.sendFile('client/index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '..') });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.get('/*', (req, res, next) => {
  if(req.url.contains('/stuff/xxx')){ // or regex match maybe
    next();
  } else {
    res.sendFile('client/index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '..') });
  }
});
```

You can add a condition matching the URL. inside this all block